# How can I show emojis on Ionic v3 application on Konva stage?

Tags: angular, ionic3, emoji, konvajs

I'm trying to make something similar to Instagram stories using Ionic v3 and I'm using KonvaJS for image manipulation/canvas related things etc.

What I want to do is adding Emoji's as text on Konva canvas. How can I achieve this? I tried to add Unicode chars to Konva.Text's text attribute but they didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just insert emoji directly and it will work just fine:

```
const text = new Konva.Text({
  x: 10,
  y: 19,
  text: ''
});
layer.add(text);
```

https://jsbin.com/wenaqeloju/1/edit?html,js,output